# Bootstrap ul navigation float right but order left to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I am trying to code a bootstrap navigation structure with 9 (don't laugh at my client please) buttons.

I want the first 5 buttons on top of the other 4, aligned to the right. The problem is that when I align them to the right, the buttons reverse in order. I solved this by creating two different lists, but that makes it reverse it when making the screen smaller. I think there should be a simple solution, but I can't find it. You can see an example at: http://www.sanderfish.nl/haptokuijpers/index.html

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-left navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="voor-wie.html">Voor wie</a></li>
            <li><a href="psychosomatiek.html">Psychosomatiek</a></li>
            <li><a href="haptotherapie.html">Haptotherapie</a></li>
            <li><a href="diana-kuijpers.html">Diana Kuijpers</a></li>
            <li><a href="vergoeding.html">Vergoeding</a></li>
            <li><a href="klachtenlijsten.html">Klachtenlijsten</a></li>
            <li><a href="uitgeverij-vib.html">Uitgeverij VIB</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

.navbar-nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
  padding-right: 34px;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 750px;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any custom CSS, just separate the two chunks of links into separate `navbar-navs`, and do `navbar-right` on the one you want to the right: DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/X0kDjEwnga

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="voor-wie.html">Voor wie</a></li>
        <li><a href="psychosomatiek.html">Psychosomatiek</a></li>
        <li><a href="haptotherapie.html">Haptotherapie</a></li>
        <li><a href="diana-kuijpers.html">Diana Kuijpers</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="vergoeding.html">Vergoeding</a></li>
        <li><a href="klachtenlijsten.html">Klachtenlijsten</a></li>
        <li><a href="uitgeverij-vib.html">Uitgeverij VIB</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

You may need to address their overlap when at specific in-between widths, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you doing this since you're overriding not only Bootstrap, but the concept of responsive design altogether, but you'll know. Anyways, simply change this part:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
}
```

to

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to bootstrap and responsive design, so could you explain me what you mean by that and how I could stop overriding that?
And your answer does work for the top row, but the bottom row is now at the left while it should be at the right. Do you now how to fix that?

Comment: very simple, you're killing all the spacing and floating everything to the left (or right) instead of stacking to the bottom as in any responsive site. Warning, this is not a SET RULE, just something that you should ponder and see if it's worth doing (or not)

Comment: I particulary see where I'm going wrong, but I don't fully understand what you mean by 'stacking to the bottom'? Thanks for the quick and accurate responses by the way.

Comment: stacking links to the bottom, I mean one link below the other in small screens, instead of one to the side of each other

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips. The other answer finally fixed it, but you definitely gave me some insights in responsive design!