# order of buttons changes when floating right. how to fix that?

Tags: html, css

When i float a few buttons to the right, the order of those buttons changes.
I uploaded picture so you can see what i mean.
[Navbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OK7S.png)

this is the code i'm using.

```css
.btn{
    float: left;
    padding: 1.7em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white; 
}
.navbar{
    float: left;
    background-color: #47476b;
}
.btnff{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.btnff:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.active{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar active" type="submit">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 3</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 4</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 5</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 6</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 7</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 8</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 9</button>
        </div>
```

how can i get button 9 and 8 in the correct order? and how can i make the color of the buttons stretch the whole width of the screen so i don't get the white space in between the left and right buttons?

Comment: just change buttons in your markup? or wrap them with block wich got .right

Comment: Can you use `position:absolute;` on them?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25940908/3185307

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap ul navigation float right but order left to right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940719/bootstrap-ul-navigation-float-right-but-order-left-to-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a container around the 2 buttons and let the container float to the right.

```css
.btn{
    float: left;
    padding: 1.7em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white; 
}
.navbar{
    float: left;
    background-color: #47476b;
}
.btnff{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.btnff:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.active{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.float-container{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
        <div>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar active" type="submit">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 3</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 4</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 5</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 6</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 7</button>
            <div class="float-container">
                <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 8</button>
                <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 9</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use text-align and only float the one you want left aligned.

You'll have to deal with white-space. here in snippet below i use a comment to get rid of it.

```css
.btn{
    float: left;
    padding: 1.7em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white; 
}
.navbar{
    float: left;
    background-color: #47476b;
}
.btnff{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.btnff:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.active{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.right{
    float: none;
}
div {text-align:right;}
```

```html
<div>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar active" type="submit">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 3</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 4</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 5</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 6</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 7</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 8</button><!-- 
                   comment to kill white-space from code indentation 
         --><button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 9</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the buttons floated right in the HTML. Add a class to the containing div and use `overflow: auto` so it doensn't collapse while containing floated child elements.

```css
.buttons {
    background: #000;
    overflow: auto;
}
.btn{
    float: left;
    padding: 1.7em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white; 
}
.navbar{
    float: left;
    background-color: #47476b;
}
.btnff{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.btnff:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.active{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn btnff navbar active" type="submit">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 3</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 4</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 5</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 6</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 7</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 9</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar right" type="submit">Button 8</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: this indeed helped me with the collerless gap between the left and right float. now i just need to figure out how to switch the place of button 8 and 9

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very effectively with flexbox, without floats:

Define the DIV container as flex container (`display: flex`), erase `float: right` from buttons 8 and 9 and assign `margin-left: auto` to button 8 (this moves everything from there on to the right end). In the code below I did that via the added classes `.x` and `.y`

```css
.btn{
    float: left;
    padding: 1.7em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white; 
}
.navbar{
    float: left;
    background-color: #47476b;
}
.btnff{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.btnff:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.active{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
   .x {
  display: flex;
   }
   .y { 
   margin-left: auto; 
   }
```

```html
<div class='x'>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar active" type="submit">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 3</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 4</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 5</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 6</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 7</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar y" type="submit">Button 8</button>
            <button class="btn btnff navbar" type="submit">Button 9</button>
        </div>
```